# Is there a built-in variable in Argo Workflows for previous/next scheduled time?

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

According to `Argo Workflows` [docs](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/variables/), there is a `workflow.scheduledTime` built-in variable but I found neither a variable for the next scheduled time nor for the previous one.

In `Airflow` for example, there are [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) that can be used to get those values.

Is there any way to get those values in Argo rather than calculate them manually inside the step itself?

Comment: It would be great to be able to re-run argo workflow for past hours in range of dates. From data engineering perspective, it makes sense to be able to re-run=backfill past scheduled e.g. on failure, on code changes.

Comment: It would also be great to be able to schedule workflows starting at specific start_date and take schedule into consideration (e.g. hourly).

Comment: in short: to be able to do in argo what airflow offers.